# populate a new list in fragment each time a list item in fragment drawer is clicked

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-listview, navigation-drawer

What i want to do is populate a new list in placeholder fragment each time a list item is clicked on fragment drawer.

What i have done is, onClick on a list item in fragment drawer i get its position value from its position value i get its foreignkey_id in SQlite database. and run a query and get the results on basis of foreign key and pass them both position and foreign key to onNavigationDrawerItemSelected in MainActivity from NavigationDrawerFragment
what i do not under stand is how to assign those values to the fragment and make the fragment manager display my values

i'm unable to understand onNavigationDrawerItemSelected and placeholderFragments section of the code
this is MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
private Context mContext = this;
Activity mActivity;

String toastMsg = null;
DatabaseHelper db;
TaskListAdapter mAdapter;

ArrayList<Task> task_data = new ArrayList<Task>();

ListView Task_listview;
TaskAdapter taskAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, int selectItemid) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    // FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    // fragmentManager
    // .beginTransaction()
    // .replace(R.id.container,
    // PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();

    try {
        task_data.clear();
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
        ArrayList<Task> task_array_from_db = db
                .Get_Tasks_Where_FK(selectItemid);
            for (int i = 0; i < contact_array_from_db.size(); i++) {
            int task_id = task_array_from_db.get(i)._id;
            String title = task_array_from_db.get(i).title;
            String details = task_array_from_db.get(i).details;
            String notes = task_array_from_db.get(i).notes;
            Task task = new Task();
            task._id = task_id ;
            task.title = title;
            task.details = details;
            task.notes = notes;
            task_data.add(task);

        db.close();
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.listview_row,
                task_data);
        Task_listview.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }// try
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("error on fragment", "creating the mainScreen");
    }// catch
    finally {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance( ))
                .commit();

    }
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }  else if (id == R.id.add_list_title) {
        return true;
    } 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(Task task) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

         //View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
         //false);
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, container,
         false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.user_task_title);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.user_task_details);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.user_task_notes);
        // TextView textView = (TextView)
        // rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        // textView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
        // ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // ((MainActivity)
        // activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
        // ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));


    }
}

}
```

this is NavigationDrawerFragment class

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {
DatabaseHelper db;
Activity mActivity;
ArrayList<TaskList> task_title_list = new ArrayList<TaskList>();
TaskListAdapterSimple mAdapter;
Button AddTaskListbtn;
String toastMsg = null;
//private int selCount = 0; // for CAB multi select count
/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
 * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;
private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private int itemSelectid = 1;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
    // awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.

    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition, itemSelectid);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
    // actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

public void Set_Refresh_Adapter_Data() { // when called assigns values to
                                            // adapter
    task_title_list.clear();
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
    ArrayList<TaskList> task_array_from_db = db.Get_TaskTitleList();
    for (int i = 0; i < task_array_from_db.size(); i++) {
        int task_id = task_array_from_db.get(i)._id;
        String title = task_array_from_db.get(i).title;
        TaskList tasklist = new TaskList();
        tasklist._id=task_id;
        tasklist.title=title;
        task_title_list.add(tasklist);
    }
    db.close();
    mAdapter = new TaskListAdapterSimple(getActivity(), R.layout.tasklist_row,
            task_title_list);
    /**
     * list view divider line, color and height
     */
    mDrawerListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(0x000000));
    mDrawerListView.setDividerHeight(1);
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@SuppressLint({ "InlinedApi", "NewApi" })
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    /**
     * adding a header to fragment
     */
    inflater = this.getLayoutInflater(savedInstanceState);
    View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
    mDrawerListView
      .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
     position--;
     int itemSelecteID =  mAdapter.getSelectedListId(position); 
     selectItem(position, itemSelecteID);
      }
      });

    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}


public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null
            && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
 * drawer interactions.
 * 
 * @param fragmentId
 *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout
 *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mActivity = getActivity();
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                     * "open drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                     * "close drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                        .apply();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
    // them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position, int selectItemid) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {

        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position, selectItemid);
    }

}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    // See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
    // action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
 * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
 * screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
 * implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, int selectItem);

}
}
```

this is my database helper

```
 public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tasksManager";

// TABLE NAMES
// Tasks table
// tasks has Auto inc. id, title, details and notes
private static final String TABLE_TASKS = "tasks";
// Task List Table
// task list has Auto inc. id and a title
private static final String TABLE_TASK_LIST = "task_list";
// Users Table
// task list has Auto inc. id name and a email
private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";
// TABLE NAMES

// Tasks Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_PK = "_id";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
private static final String KEY_DETAILS = "details";
private static final String KEY_NOTES = "notes";
private static final String KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID = "fk_tasklist_id";

private final ArrayList<Task> task_list = new ArrayList<Task>();

// Task List Table Columns names
// id and title and as above

private final ArrayList<TaskList> task_title_list = new ArrayList<TaskList>();

// SQLite Create Queries
// Tasks Table
private static final String CREATE_TASKS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_TASKS 
        + "(" 
        + KEY_PK
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DETAILS + " TEXT," + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT," 
        + KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID + " INTEGER,"
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID + ")" 
        + "REFERENCES " 
        + TABLE_TASK_LIST + "("+ KEY_PK + ")" 
        + ")";

private static final String CREATE_TASK_LIST_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + TABLE_TASK_LIST + "(" + KEY_PK
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT" + ")";


public DatabaseHelper(Context cContext) {
    super(cContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

// Creating Tables
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TASKS_TABLE);// create task table
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onCreate Error", "TASKS_TABLE not created");
    }
    try {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TASK_LIST_TABLE);// create task list table
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("onCreate Error", "TASK_LIST_TABLE not created");
    }
}

// Upgrading database
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    try {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASKS);// Drop Task Table
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_TASK_LIST);// Drop Task
        onCreate(db);// Create tables again
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Database onUpgrade", "not created");
    }
}

/**
 * All CRUD FOR TASK(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */
// Add new Task
public void Add_Task(Task task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, task.title);
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, task.details);
    values.put(KEY_NOTES, task.notes);
    values.put(KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID, task.fk_tasklist_id);
    db.insert(TABLE_TASKS, null, values);
    db.close();
}

// Delete a Task
public void Delete_Task(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TASKS, KEY_PK + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    db.close();
}

// Updating a Task
public int Update_Task(Task task) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, task.title);
    values.put(KEY_DETAILS, task.details);
    values.put(KEY_NOTES, task.notes);
    return db.update(TABLE_TASKS, values, KEY_PK + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(task._id) });// updating row
}

// Getting single Task
Task Get_Task(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASKS, new String[] { KEY_PK, KEY_TITLE,
            KEY_DETAILS, KEY_NOTES,KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID }, KEY_PK + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    Task task = new Task(
                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                        cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),
                        cursor.getString(3),
                        Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4))
                        );
    // return Task
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return task;
}

// Getting All Tasks
public ArrayList<Task> Get_Tasks() {
    try {
        task_list.clear();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Task task = new Task();
                task._id=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                task.title=(cursor.getString(1));
                task.details =(cursor.getString(2));
                task.notes=(cursor.getString(3));
            //  task.fk_tasklist_id=(cursor.getString(4));
                // Adding Task to list
                task_list.add(task);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Task list
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return task_list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("all_Task", "DBHelper GetTasks" + e);
    }

    return task_list;
}

// Getting Tasks Count
public int Get_Total_Tasks() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
// Getting All Tasks
public ArrayList<Task> Get_Tasks_Where_FK(int id) {
    try {
        task_list.clear();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASKS + " WHERE " + KEY_FK_TASKLIST_ID + " = " + id;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Task task = new Task();
                task._id=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                task.title=(cursor.getString(1));
                task.details =(cursor.getString(2));
                task.notes=(cursor.getString(3));
                task.fk_tasklist_id=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
                // Adding Task to list
                task_list.add(task);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Task list
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return task_list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("all_Task", "DBHelper GetTasks" + e);
    }

    return task_list;
}

/**
 * All CRUD FOR TASK LIST(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
 */
// Add a TaskList
public void Add_TaskList(TaskList tasklist) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, tasklist.title);
    db.insert(TABLE_TASK_LIST, null, values);
    db.close();
}

// Delete a TaskList
public void Delete_TaskList(int id) {//recento
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_TASK_LIST, KEY_PK + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
    db.close();
}

// Updating single Task
public int Update_TaskList(TaskList tasklist) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, tasklist.title);
    return db.update(TABLE_TASK_LIST, values, KEY_PK + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(tasklist._id) });
}

// Getting All TasksLists
public ArrayList<TaskList> Get_TaskTitleList() {
    try {
        task_title_list.clear();

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASK_LIST;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                TaskList tasklist = new TaskList();
                tasklist._id=(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                tasklist.title=(cursor.getString(1));
                // Adding Task to list
                task_title_list.add(tasklist);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return Task list
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return task_title_list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        Log.e("all_TaskTitleList", "DBHelper GetTaskTitleList" + e);
    }

    return task_title_list;
}

// Getting single TaskList
TaskList Get_TaskList(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_TASK_LIST, new String[] { KEY_PK,
            KEY_TITLE }, KEY_PK + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    TaskList tasklist = new TaskList(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1));// return TaskList
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return tasklist;
}

// Getting Tasks Count
public int Get_Total_TaskList() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_TASK_LIST;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();
    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

and this is my adapter

```
public class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {
Activity activity;
NavigationDrawerFragment navigationDrawerFragment;
int layoutResourceId;
Task user;
ArrayList<Task> data = new ArrayList<Task>();
private HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

public TaskAdapter(Activity act, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<Task> data) {
    super(act, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.activity = act;
    this.data = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public Task getSingularSelectedTask() {
    if (mSelection.size() == 1) {
        for (Integer temp : getCurrentCheckedPosition())
            return data.get(temp);
    }
    return null;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> getSelectedTasks() {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        if (isPositionChecked(i)) {
            temp.add(data.get(i)._id);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

public void setNewSelection(int position, boolean value) {
    mSelection.put(position, value);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public boolean isPositionChecked(int position) {
    Boolean result = mSelection.get(position);
    return result == null ? false : result;
}

public Set<Integer> getCurrentCheckedPosition() {
    return mSelection.keySet();
}

public void removeSelection(int position) {
    mSelection.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void clearSelection() {
    mSelection = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    UserHolder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        // LayoutInflater inflater =
        // LayoutInflater.from(navigationDrawerFragment);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new UserHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_task_title);
        holder.details = (TextView) row
                .findViewById(R.id.user_task_details);
        holder.notes = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.user_task_notes);

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (UserHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    row.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
            android.R.color.background_light)); // default color

    if (mSelection.get(position) != null) {
        row.setBackgroundColor(activity.getResources().getColor(
                android.R.color.holo_blue_light));
    }
    user = data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(user.title);
    holder.details.setText(user.details);
    holder.notes.setText(user.notes);
    return row;

}

class UserHolder {
    TextView title;
    TextView details;
    TextView notes;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solved my problem

```
   public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position, int selectItemid) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
        task_data.clear();
```

this section same as above till here, calling db for loop and asssignment

```
            task_data.add(task);
            db.close();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(
                            R.id.container,
                            PlaceholderFragment
                                    .newInstance(task_data, this)).commit();
 }

}
```

// these changes in Placeholder fragment

```
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(
        ArrayList<Task> task_data, Activity activity) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        mActivity = activity;
        data = task_data;
        return fragment;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        Task_listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        taskAdapter = new TaskAdapter(mActivity, R.layout.listview_row,
                data);
        Task_listview.setAdapter(taskAdapter);
        taskAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return rootView;
    }
```